# git merge doesn't raise conflicts

Tags: git, github, merge

Me and one of my colleague works on the same project.
We both didn't use git everytime we individually made changes.
But now we wanted to merge our projects together.

What I did was, I initialized git in my project folder.
I committed all the changes.
I made another, let's call it "`A`". I "`checkout`" that branch and added all his folders and files to the project folder manually.
Then I added and committed the changes.

Then I check(ed) out "`master`" branch and entered: "`git merge A`". It merged everything but did'nt raise any conflicts.
What it basically did was automatically merged it, removing half of my original files and adding his.

I don't want it to happen this way. What we want is, git should merge everything and raise conflicts for everything. EVERYTHING.
And let me do all the changes manually.
Is there any way to do that?

Edit: 
this line

```
git checkout @~
```

gives me this:

```
$ git checkout @~
Note: checking out '@~'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 9a3e723... Asc
```

this removes half of my files again. But when i 'checkout master' again. My files are back there.

Comment: You might want to learn more about merging: https://learningpassion.wordpress.com/2016/06/20/git-tutorial-day-to-day-use-part-7-merging/

Comment: "this removes half of my files again." : this is expected: you need to go back to the empty commit before adding the other code. See my complete example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What it basically did was automatically merged it, removing half of my original files and adding his

That makes sense considering you recorded A on top of master:

```
--x (master)
   \
    y (A, where some folders are missing)
```

A `git merge` reports the modifications from `A` on top of `master`, as a fast-forward merge.

```
 git checkout master
 git merge A

-- x--y (master, A)
```

What you want to do is 2 branches starting from an empty commit:

```
git init .
git commit --allow-empty -m "First initial empty commit"
git add .
git commit -m "My code"
git checkout @~
git checkout -b A
# copy other code
git add .
git commit -m "other code"
```

Then you can merge:

```
--E--x (master)
   \
    y (A)
```

That will result in conflicts, since the common ancestor this time is '`E`' (the empty commit), meaning concurrent changes were recorded both in `master` and in `A` since that initial commit.

```
git checkout master
git merge A

--E--x--M (master)
   \   /
    y-- (A)
```

---

## Test

### Initialize new repo

```
vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git init .
> git commit --allow-empty -m "empty"
[master (root-commit) ba36e82] empty
```

### Add my code 'm' and a common folder 'c'

```
vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> mkdir m
> touch m\m.txt
> mkdir c
> echo c>c\c.txt
> touch c\cm.txt

vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git add .

vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git st
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   c/c.txt
        new file:   c/cm.txt
        new file:   m/m.txt


vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git commit -m "m head"
[master 7c1a82d] m head
 3 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 c/c.txt
 create mode 100644 c/cm.txt
 create mode 100644 m/m.txt
```

### Create branch `A` from empty commit:

```
vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git checkout @~
Note: checking out '@~'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at ba36e82... empty

vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-yyyy

 Directory of C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge

27/07/2016  13:37    <DIR>          .
27/07/2016  13:37    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  325 054 046 208 bytes free

vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git checkout -b A
Switched to a new branch 'A'
```

### In branch `A`, add the other code (which updates a common folder)

```
vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> mkdir a
> touch a\a.txt

vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> mkdir c
> echo e>c\c.txt
> touch c\f.txt

vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git add .

> git st
On branch A
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   a/a.txt
        new file:   c/c.txt
        new file:   c/f.txt


vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git commit -m "a head"
[A 3168bae] a head
 3 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a/a.txt
 create mode 100644 c/c.txt
 create mode 100644 c/f.txt
```

### Switch back to `master`, and merge `A` into `master`:

```
vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> glab
* 3168bae - (A) a head (80 seconds ago) <VonC>
| * 7c1a82d - (HEAD -> master) m head (3 minutes ago) <VonC>
|/
* ba36e82 - empty (4 minutes ago) <VonC>

vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-yyyy

 Directory of C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge

27/07/2016  13:41    <DIR>          .
27/07/2016  13:41    <DIR>          ..
27/07/2016  13:41    <DIR>          c
27/07/2016  13:41    <DIR>          m
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  325 051 240 448 bytes free
```

### The merge does produce a conflicts for concurrent changes

```
vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git merge A
Auto-merging c/c.txt
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in c/c.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

vonc@voncm C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> git st
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

        new file:   a/a.txt
        new file:   c/f.txt

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both added:      c/c.txt
```

### No folders were removed:

```
vonc@WSV00320606 C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge
> dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-yyyy

 Directory of C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\tests\merge

27/07/2016  13:41    <DIR>          .
27/07/2016  13:41    <DIR>          ..
27/07/2016  13:41    <DIR>          a
27/07/2016  13:41    <DIR>          c
27/07/2016  13:41    <DIR>          m
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  325 005 889 536 bytes free
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you please explain me what we exactly did here:
`git init .
git commit --allow-empty -m "First initial empty commit"
git add .
git commit -m "My code"
git reset --hard @~
git checkout -b A
# copy other code
git add .
git commit -m "other code"
`

Comment: @AshishKulkarni You import your code in a *second* commit, after creating a first one empty. Then you reset back to that empty commit, create another branch and add the other code there.

Comment: That didn't give me any conflicts. Instead what it did was, it deleted all my folders in the master branch. Then when i added all the folders to the A branch, it simply added those files and folder to the master branch when i merged them.

Comment: @AshishKulkarni That is because you are still in the first case, and not working with two commits done from one common empty commit.

Comment: @AshishKulkarni I just tested it: there was an error in my instruction: replace reset by checkout: see edit http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38606868/revisions

Comment: Hi VonC, it doesn't work. I'm still not getting the conflicts. It is fast forwarding. I tried this for 4-5 times. Doesn't work What should I do?

Comment: @AshishKulkarni Can you edit your questio with the exact command you are using? I will edit my answer with a complete example for you to see.

Comment: @AshishKulkarni I have updated the answer with a complete example

Comment: @AshishKulkarni Great \o/ Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer